# Windows 8 refuses to install on new partition created using Boot Camp

Tags: windows-8, mac, osx-lion, boot-camp

I'm trying to install Windows 8 on my Mac (10.7.5) but I'm running into some big issues. First I'll explain what I already did.

1. I created a partition with the Boot camp assistant (151 GB)  [image]
2. I installed a **ISO** on my external hard drive.
3. I rebooted my Mac holding the option key so I could choose a start drive disk
4. I selected **EFI BOOT** [image]
5. I entered my serial number and continued.

**And here does the trouble begins:**

6. Now a see a list of drivers and my partition but I can't select my `Drive 0 Partition 4: Bootcamp` [image]

The error I get:

> "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk has an
>   MBR partition table. On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed to
>   GPT disks.
>
> Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space. Windows must be
>   installed to a partition formatted as NTFS.
>
> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may
>   not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disk's controller is
>   enabled in the computer's BIOS menu"

I already tried to run this command(s)

```
diskpart
select disk 0                      (assuming 0 is the disk where you created the bootcamp partition)
select partition 4                 (assuming 4 is your bootcamp partition)
format fs=NTFS label="Windows 8"   (I didn’t use QUICK)
exit
exit
```

**Note: Drive 1 is my external hard disk.**

Answer (score 2):

It was happened also to me, from my personal experience, I had addressed the problem in that way:

1. Select Boot Camp partition.
2. Click on Drive Option (Advanced).
3. Erase it.
4. Select the new blank partition and click Next to install Windows on it.
5. After login in Windows, you can [download Boot Camp driver from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720) and install.